# two nested v-for loops of which the inner one shouldn’t display its element but is needed for getting class attributes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, v-for

how would we solve having two nested v-for loops (elements), of which one is solely for getting class attributes and shouldn't display its div element? because it is of course displaying its element in each iteration and causing a break in the layout and displaying duplicated data because of those iterations

DESIRED OUTCOME:
I need to be able to use values from an array, for the column width of the rendered values of a loop, as interpolation in the class attribute along with their corresponding rendered values.

live example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-kkzp2g?file=src/components/HelloNestedLoop.vue

Comment: Why must it be a `<div>` element? why not use a non-breaking element for the inner v-for loop, such as a `<span>` element?

Comment: And can you tell more of the details of your problem that you're trying to solve, your code, and show your code not as an image but as code-formatted text, preferably as a decent [mre]?

Comment: I think you should compute a new array that will create this list of objects with class information and on that array, you can use for loop.

Comment: added live example. tried span, also template element, to no avail. @Atul I'm not sure how you intend to do this / accomplish the wanted result or approach in particular

Comment: As @atul suggested: use a computed property to structure your data the way you need it, instead of trying to hack around it inside the template.

Comment: The desired result is not clear.

Comment: @DanielBeck this wouldn't make any difference, since I already have that array. How would you structure an array, to loop through it with one for-loop, to use values for class attribute interpolation AND values for displaying data at the same time anyway?

Comment: The comment isn't constructive. @tao

Comment: I wanted you to know three things: 1) I have extensive knowledge of vue; 2) I'm willing to help you achieve what you're after; 3) I don't understand what the desired outcome is, and therefore am unable to help. I didn't mean my comment to be constructive. I wanted you to be aware you might be able to avail of my help while I'm focusing your question, if you could provide more detail on what it is you want to achieve. Could you present the desired HTML output? I believe you don't need a nested `v-for`, if you're only doing a `v-for` for looping through classes. You can use a `.map` in `:class`.

Comment: "How would you structure an array, to loop through it with one for-loop, to use values for class attribute interpolation AND values for displaying data at the same time anyway".  Like this: `<template v-for="foo in bar"><div :class="foo.a">{{foo.b}}</div></template>`

Comment: ...or have I misunderstood what you asked?  Because I have to agree with @tao, if you'd just tell us your expected output you'd be a lot likelier to get answers that lead toward it

Comment: You're trying to set `col-3` on the first column and `col-1` on the rest. [Here it is](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-fbtspx?file=src/components/HelloNestedLoop.vue). Be aware it's not a good solution on mobile devices, the columns overlap below 500px. [This](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-j55j1i?file=src/components/HelloNestedLoop.vue) is likely a better solution. Having solved your problem without answering your question indicates your question was a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Which is why I asked what's the desired outcome in the first place.

Comment: oh well, I see, thanks for your help. @tao that's it, thank you. And - 1 & 2 weren't clear from your comment. Just wanted to address this. But I think you know I implied with my response that I did my best to describe the desired outcome. Even set up a live env to play around with and still get downvoted  this platform.

Comment: 1 & 2 would have been obvious if you took the time to look at my profile. Don't worry about it. Always happy to help. To be fair, putting up the [mcve] is what allowed me to understand what you're really asking. Without it I had no chance, considering your question. Cheers!

Comment: If you would have told me what's not clear on my written 'desired outcome', I would have been glad to be able to improve on that. I admit, it was written quite hasty.

Comment: It wasn't clear you wanted to place `col-3` on the first column and `col-1` on the other three columns. If you asked exactly that, you'd have received 5 answers in the first three minutes (probably all the same but, still, solving your problem).

Comment: hmm that's only the case with this specific hardcoded data. that's why I thought it wouldn't make sense to word it that way - because it needs to be dynamic. will take this definitely into account next time :)

Comment: Side note: there's another, more subtle problem with your initial approach: property order in objects, in JavaScript, is not guaranteed. Therefore, iterating through the entries of an object and then pairing those with the entries in an array is considered unsafe, as it might produce unexpected results on particular JavaScript engines/in particular browsers. To make sure they're always correct you'd have to specify the widths like `columns: { url: 3, cls: 1, fid: 1, lcp: 1}` and access them by `key`.

Comment: To give you an example: consider you have an update method for your rows. Let's say you update the `url` of one entry. You'd write something like `newItem = { ...oldItem, url: newUrl }`. You'll notice the order of columns in your table is changed for that row. Which is why you normally should have a fields array, in whatever order you want your columns, get the field key from the position in that array and read that key from current row. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`<template>`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html?redirect=true#Conditional-Groups-with-v-if-on-lt-template-gt) tag instead of `<div>` for the outer element:

```
<template v-for="...">
  <div v-for="...">
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: already tried, as this seemed reasonable, but doesn't change anything